# Multilingual Comments on my website

Tags: language, comments

I have a website which contains description, title, cover of movie or some other things.
On the bottom I have Facebook comments.

I have a 2 questions.

**Should I change Facebook comments to Disqus comments?**

**Comments should be universal or separate for each language?** (website Available in English, Armenian and Russian, should I separate comment block for single entity, let's say movie or all users should see all comments about that movie and be able to discuss in different languages?)

Comment: Don't make it harder than it is: keep all comments visible to all visitors. Your visitors may speak more than one of the languages in which your site is available.

Comment: Let's say there are 5 comments in Russian. American commenter won't post a comment in that list.

Answer (score 2):

If the content itself is in Spanish, you should indeed ensure that comments would be localized to match the content.  You risk potentially confusing people who see Spanish comments when viewing a video in English or vice versa.

I've seen multiple sites (like Spotify) do this sort of thing. Then you have Youtube that has a general comment board. I don't believe there is a common practice.

However if you don't want the comments that are the type of "speak English in here" or more racist type comments which do happen, it may work best to break them apart. Though at times some people who's primary language is Spanish may speak English and will comment in English.

I think there are fair arguments for whichever direction you choose. I personally prefer to see all comments if there aren't many comments made in general. But as the site gets more popular you may want to break them up based on feedback.

As for commenting systems, I very much prefer Disqus.

Answer (score 0):

I run multiple sites, some use Facebook Comments (https://raptortranslations.com) and some use Disqus Comments (https://InternationalAviationHQ.com). As a genera rule, I don’t really see much of a difference between the two for my own DA (domain authority).

Personally, I find Disqus easier to manage, as they can be set up to auto accept, and spammy comments are often removed for me, rather than me having to do it, like I have to do it with the Facebook comments at times.